# класс Menu как работает код

Tags: javascript, классы

```js
  class Menu {
    constructor(elem) {
      this.elem = elem;
      elem.onclick = this.onClick.bind(this); // (*)
    }

    save() {
      alert('сохраняю');
    }

    load() {
      alert('загружаю');
    }

    search() {
      alert('ищу');
    }

    onClick(event) {
      let action = event.target.dataset.action;
      if (action) {
        this[action]();
      }
    };
  }

  let d = new Menu(menu);

  console.log(d);
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <button data-action="save">Сохранить</button>
  <button data-action="load">Загрузить</button>
  <button data-action="search">Поиск</button>
</div>
```

Объясните алгоритм выполнения кода я запутался ...

Comment: привязывается контекст https://learn.javascript.ru/bind

Comment: @Lev Shportak какой в onClick.bind(this); будет контекст ?